# Get inherited object type at runtime

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, interface, types

If you consider:

```
class A : IInterface { }
```

at runtime:

```
A instance = new A();

instance.GetType(); // returns "A"
```

or

```
IInterface instance = new A();

instance.GetType(); // returns "A"
```

or

```
object instance = new A();
instance.GetType(); // returns "A"
```

**Question:** How to get `IInterface` as Type ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`instance.GetType().GetInterfaces()` will get all the interfaces implemented or inherited by the instance type [*(Type.GetInterfaces Method)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

GetType() will always give you the type of the class you have an instance of, no matter what kind of reference you have to it.  You've observed this in your question.

If you're always looking to get a type object for IInterface, you could also use

```
typeof(IInterface)
```

If you need a list of interfaces which the type implements, you can use

```
instance.GetType().GetInterfaces()
```

Answer (score 2):

Check `Type.GetInterface` method:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcctb9t8(v=VS.100).aspx

Instead of trying to get a casted to some interface object, you need to check if the object implements such interface. If so, you can cast it to the interface type or, if you're looking to print the type to some stream, if it implements the interface, print the string representation of it.

You can implement an extension method like next one in order to make life easier:

```
public static bool Implements<T>(this Type some)
{
    return typeof(T).IsInterface && some.GetInterfaces().Count(someInterface => someInterface == typeof(T)) == 1;

}
```

And, finally, you can do that:

```
Type interfaceType = someObject.GetType().Implements<IInterface>() ? typeof(IInterface) : default(Type);
```

Comment: No problem to cast if interface is known, but I'm doing something depending on runtime known interfaces, so the GetInterfaces() collection is perfect match for this.

Comment: Then you can follow the extension method approach. It'll make your code cleaner than repeating the thing you're encapsulating with it a lot of times in your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

See Scott Hanselmans pretty good article on that topic:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DoesATypeImplementAnInterface.aspx

```
   Type type = instance.GetType()
   Type[] ifaces = type.GetInterfaces()
```

Should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check for a particular interface you can use the 'is' keyword
        if(instance is IInterface)
            //do something